# How to reset Nexus One to Android 2.2.1 or 2.3?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, nexus-one, 2.3-gingerbread

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

I have a Nexus One (with the radios for the AT&T network) which has an old beta version of 2.2 on it. It doesn't receive over the air updates, and I'd like to get it running something more recent.

Where can I find a download for Android 2.2.1 or 2.3? There's a link to an updater on Google's site that's given by numerous blogs but it's always broken. It's kind of bizarre to me that this phone is stuck in an OS limbo since it won't receive updates and there's no place to download the latest.

Comment: Not to state the obvious but have you tried doing a factory reset? How did the phone get the beta version of 2.2 onto it, that might help other people help with suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You might have more luck installing a third party ROM as it's not always easy to get the original AOSP (Android Open Source Project) running on your device. Having the Nexus One is good for you since it'll be one of the first phones to actually get ROMs.

If you want 2.3, google for the "Oxygen ROM".

Otherwise, I think there's an original Nexus One ROM [right on XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=614057).

I also found another board topic that has several [Nexus One Stock ROMs](http://android.modaco.com/content/google-nexus-one-nexusone-modaco-com/300414/21-oct-stock-roms-erd79-frg83-images-zip-online-kitchen-optional-root-insecure/) and you can even customize and "bake" them yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Why not stick [CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/) on it? Essentially the same thing with a few extra bonuses ;)