# How can I reload original software back to nexus one

Tags: nexus-one, stock-android

I unlock my nexus one, and compile and install the ginger bread build load to the phone. But now, I realize that it does not have all the google software e.g. gmail, map, market, etc.

How can I reset my nexus one back to the original froyo with all the google software?

I have tried 'factory reset' but it does not revert back to android 2.2. Thank you for any idea.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4678/how-to-reset-nexus-one-to-android-2-2-1-or-2-3 That question has no accepted answer, but it was migrated here so the asker doesn't have an account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this thread, [Original ROM](http://androidforums.com/nexus-all-things-root/258265-original-rom.html), which is about returning a Nexus One to an unmodded ROM.

Answer (score 1):

Is your phone also rooted?  You could install ROM Manager, and then Clockwork Recovery.  ROM Manager has an option to flash a stock ROM back onto a phone (with or without root status).

Or you could try out CyanogenMod.  CM7 nightlies just started, so we should see a stable version soon.  (CM7 has Gingerbread with optional Google Apps.  CM6 is Froyo.)